# Eclipse "compare with" context menus with mercurial eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, stm32, mcu

I have been using the Mercurial Eclipse for MCU projects in System Workbench for STM32 IDE for a while. It allowed me to right click on a file or folder and use the compare with option in the context menu to compare against other file versions from the Mercurial repository. Recently due to a lack of support for a newer MCU, I had to move to the STM32CubeIDE. It is still eclipse based so I expected that I could install Mercurial Eclipse and have the same functionality. But what I have found is that the compare with context menu does not give the option to compare against previous versions. Even in the history view, I cannot compare one changeset against another.

It does appear that STM32CubeIDE uses a newer Eclipse version. The Eclipse versions are:

For STM32CubeIDE

Version: 4.19.0.v20210303-1800
Build id: I20210303-1800

For System Workbench

Version: 4.6.3.v20170301-0400
Build id: M20170301-0400

Does anyone know if there is a way to get these context menus to work with the newer Eclipse version?